# Mounts happening on boot, but not defined in /etc/fstab

Tags: centos, centos7, mount, fstab, df

On every boot, my machine (CentOS 7) mounts all these:

```
# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        30G  2.6G   28G   9% /
devtmpfs        287M     0  287M   0% /dev
tmpfs           294M     0  294M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           294M   34M  261M  12% /run
tmpfs           294M     0  294M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

But my /etc/fstab only contains these:

```
# cat /etc/fstab
UUID=823db525-82d9-467e-acdf-7379cbd85171 /    xfs     defaults        0 0
```

**Where would all the mounts of "tmpfs" be defined?

Where can I configure their sizes?**

If I add more entries in my /etc/fstab, such as something like:

```
tmpfs       /dev/shm     tmpfs   defaults,noatime      0 0
```

Would that cause a conflict with whatever setting is already mounting that on boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CentOS 7 uses systemd.
Systemd will create some [API File Systems](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems/)  automatically, with default (kernel) settings but you can still add those to `/etc/fstab` to use custom options:

> ... Even though normally none of these API file systems are listed in `/etc/fstab` they may be added there. If so, any options specified therein will be applied to that specific API file system. Hence: **to alter the mount options or other parameters of these file systems, simply add them to `/etc/fstab` with the appropriate settings and you are done**...

In addition to the conventional `/etc/fstab` control file  systemd  supports `.mount` unit files which can be used to manage your custom mounts.
See [`man systemd.mount`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html) for more detail.

Comment: That makes all the sense and answers my question! Thank you very much.